# Requirejs and external scripts

Tags: javascript, html, oop, requirejs, external-script

Hi I have my js application that was built with requirejs. Now I have external page from other developer, he can load his scripts, html, css and other things that not connected to me. 
Here example of my module that will be connected to his page:

```
require(['page', 'widgetGame', 'adDynamic'], function (Page, WidgetGame, AdDynamic) {
    function PageExternalGame (params) {
        var params = params || {}; 
        Page.call(this, params); // call super constructor.
    };

    PageExternalGame.prototype.gameLoadingComplete = function() {
        alert(111);
    };

    window.yepiExternalPageGame = new PageExternalGame();
    return PageExternalGame;
});
```

and here example of his page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"><head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='gameArea'>
<canvas id='canvas0' width='480' height='320' style="position: absolute; "></canvas>
</div>
<script data-main="../../YepiMobileNew/UI/js/pageExternalGame" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src='js/gamemin.js'></script>
<script>yepiExternalPageGame.gameLoadingComplete()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So in his page he call my object yepiExternalPageGame, that should be loaded by requirejs. but when he call this object, require itself already loaded, but class pageExternalGame still wasn't loaded, so this object is not exist when he call it. How to handle with it? (His outer scripts also can call my object). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you sharing your amd app with other it is good to create build that isn't using require.js so you won't force other developers to add another lib and increase page size. You can do this with almond.js

But returning to your question.

Change

```
<script>yepiExternalPageGame.gameLoadingComplete()</script>
```

to

```
<script>
    require(['../../YepiMobileNew/UI/js/pageExternalGame'], function() {
        yepiExternalPageGame.gameLoadingComplete();
    });
</script>
```

That will help.